# Born of Sunbeams and Fire

Tags: riddle

Journey far west in the US of A
Err to the south a bit, too
True, you can't stay here (it's too rich for most)
For sure, only the wealthiest do

Usually, I solo; few sing the same
Everyone says, though, I'm always alone
Like some of my kind, I have few worthy partners
Clever are those who know

As a warrior I supported the war
Never did they stand up to me
Too violent, was I, and hurt many of mine
Man, though, did I clear those trees

Emperor am I, or so it seems
Legally, I've just been Freed
Truly, consume me, I will not mind
Such is my will inclined

Too often compared to another, am I
Even though we are mostly the same
Everyone sees only differences, but
Largely, we can be interchanged

Born of sunbeams and fire
Evoking warm feelings in most

Alone I fulfill some of this riddle
Mixed with another, the rest
So, can you name me and my partners above?

---

**Clarification to avoid the dangers of being too broad:**

Each stanza except the last one has a specific answer that is different from the rest of the stanzas. Those answers will have a common word. That common word is the answer for the last stanza and the overall puzzle. (This is what I have tried to hint at in the last stanza but it might not have been clear enough.)

Comment: You crafty son of a...

Comment: Jet fuel can't melt steel beams.

Comment: @Randal'Thor that was the first thing I noticed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is:

> Orange

Journey far west in the US of A
Err to the south a bit, too
True, you can't stay here (it's too rich for most)
For sure, only the wealthiest do

> Orange County

Usually, I solo; few sing the same
Everyone says, though, I'm always alone
Like some of my kind, I have few worthy partners
Clever are those who know

> No words rhyme with "orange"

As a warrior I supported the war
Never did they stand up to me
Too violent, was I, and hurt many of mine
Man, though, did I clear those trees

> Agent orange

Emperor am I, or so it seems
Legally, I've just been Freed
Truly, consume me, I will not mind
Such is my will inclined

> Orange Julius (invented by Julius Freed apparently)

Too often compared to another, am I
Even though we are mostly the same
Everyone sees only differences, but
Largely, we can be interchanged

> Apples and oranges

Born of sunbeams and fire
Evoking warm feelings in most

> Orange color/light

Alone I fulfill some of this riddle
Mixed with another, the rest
So, can you name me and my partners above?

> Orange is in all the answers above

Comment: Stanza 2: Singing partners need to sound alike. Stanza 4: As in weed? No. The capitalization is accurate. Otherwise, correct! Check mark for you. +1 if you can fix those two.

Comment: Daaang, would never have found that , no idea what orange kush or agent orange is.

Comment: @EngineerToast Still no idea on #2.  Is #4 "Mandarin orange"?

Comment: @Spacemonkey Orange kush is marijuana.  I thought that was the answer because it was recently legalized.  Agent orange is a defoliant they used in the Vietnam War (a defoliant kills plants: to clear out the jungle).  It ended up having side effects on the soldiers that used it though.

Comment: @JSI #4 is a beverage named after someone who's last name is Freed and whose first name is the missing blank in "Orange ______"

Comment: @EngineerToast Ok I got #4.  I still don't have any idea on #2.  Maybe I don't know enough about music...

Comment: #2 is kinda weak and you got the rest so I'll be more obvious without just straight-up telling you: "______ with Orange" or even "_____ that _____ with Orange". Singing together requires that you sound alike.

Comment: @EngineerToast Ok I think I got it know.  I was thinking music related and I totally didn't understand the clue.

Answer (score 2):

> To me it clearly evokes California and it's regions.

**--------------------------------------------------**

Journey far west in the US of A
Err to the south a bit, too
True, you can't stay here (it's too rich for most)
For sure, only the wealthiest do

> Sillicon Valley or any other really rich California locale (Malibu, etc...)

Usually, I solo; few sing the same
Everyone says, though, I'm always alone
Like some of my kind, I have few worthy partners
Clever are those who know

> Unsure

As a warrior I supported the war
Never did they stand up to me
Too violent, was I, and hurt many of mine
Man, though, did I clear those trees

> Redwood/Sequoias/Douglas fir forests in the north, conflicts in it's history including those with the spaniards and native americans

Emperor am I, or so it seems
Legally, I've just been Freed
Truly, consume me, I will not mind
Such is my will inclined

> Inland Empire and Marijuana Legalization

Too often compared to another, am I
Even though we are mostly the same
Everyone sees only differences, but
Largely, we can be interchanged

> Not sure of this one either but could be a bunch of stuff, one of the most hilarious in my opinion would be the comparison of Hollywood and Bollywood

Born of sunbeams and fire
Evoking warm feelings in most
Alone I fulfill some of this riddle
Mixed with another, the rest

> Part of the pacific ring of fire, also it is the sunshine state

Comment: This is not my answer although your explanation for the first stanza is pretty close (it's just not precise enough). I especially liked your explanation for the last stanza. The last stanza gives a clue to how the final answer fits into all the clues.

Comment: The sunshine state is Florida

Comment: whoops my bad, I'm not from the states so I'll use that as my excuse :D

Comment: Now I'm thinking stars or earthquakes lol. good riddle

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by spacemonkey's answer, I say

> Marijuana, Cannabis

Journey far west in the US of A
Err to the south a bit, too
True, you can't stay here (it's too rich for most)
For sure, only the wealthiest do

> In the south-west coast of US Cannabis isn't completely legalized. California, which is in the South-West coast, is a very rich State.

Usually, I solo; few sing the same
Everyone says, though, I'm always alone
Like some of my kind, I have few worthy partners
Clever are those who know

> I'm not an expert of drugs, but I think that cannabis is consumed alone, without other drugs. Similar drugs (partners) can be all the smokable weeds. Sing might be a reference to artists who used to smoke cannabis, like Bob Marley and many others.

As a warrior I supported the war
Never did they stand up to me
Too violent, was I, and hurt many of mine
Man, though, did I clear those trees

> During wars, cannabis is used to placate the soldiers and to distract them from the violence. Many trees were cut down to make room for marijuana plantations.

Emperor am I, or so it seems
Legally, I've just been Freed
Truly, consume me, I will not mind
Such is my will inclined

> Many countries recently legalized Cannabis.

Too often compared to another, am I
Even though we are mostly the same
Everyone sees only differences, but
Largely, we can be interchanged

> I don't know what Marijuana is compared to, maybe Hashish? The origin is indeed the same, probably the effects are similar as well.

Born of sunbeams and fire
Evoking warm feelings in most
Alone I fulfill some of this riddle
Mixed with another, the rest

> Sun makes the plants grow. Cannabis can stimulate memories sometimes. One (Marijuana) mixed with the other (Hashish) can explain the lines of this riddle pretty well, imo.

Comment: I was just looking into the same thing, but i can't see how a few lines fit...also, the riddle is asking for at least 3 things-- "me and my partners"

Comment: @JLee We urgently need the help of a serial smoker

Comment: I can confirm this is also not my answer. Drugs are bad, mkay? However, since you people are so darn clever, I have added some clarification to explain the structure of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> GOLD. **Edit**: actually, maybe it's BAR.

*Journey far west in the US of A

 Err to the south a bit, too

 True, you can't stay here (it's too rich for most)

 For sure, only the wealthiest do*

> California, the Golden State, could be referring to gold bars.

*Usually, I solo; few sing the same

 Everyone says, though, I'm always alone

 Like some of my kind, I have few worthy partners

 Clever are those who know*

> Bars of song.

*As a warrior I supported the war

 Never did they stand up to me

 Too violent, was I, and hurt many of mine

 Man, though, did I clear those trees*

> Not sure about this verse.

*Emperor am I, or so it seems

 Legally, I've just been Freed

 Truly, consume me, I will not mind

 Such is my will inclined*

> This sounds like a [penguin bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguin_%28biscuit%29). There exist Emperor Penguins; penguin bars can be bought (freed?) and eaten (consumed).

*Too often compared to another, am I

 Even though we are mostly the same

 Everyone sees only differences, but

 Largely, we can be interchanged*

> Not sure about this verse either.

*Born of sunbeams and fire

 Evoking warm feelings in most*

> Sunbeams and fire are golden.

Comment: I got really excited when you said it was gold and then less excited when you explained why. You're not as close as I thought at first.

Comment: @EngineerToast If I may ask for a hint, is gold closer than bar?

Comment: Yes. Gold is closer.